# Why app/console config:dump-reference framework Bundle configuration dump is different from the configuration of the bundle inside the app/config?

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, bundle

I am reading the book and I saw that you can dump the configuration of a bundle on the console using the command:

```
app/console config:dump-reference framework
```

From the CLI. I was wondering why the configuration of the bundle is different from the one inside the app/config/config.yml, so can someone tell me please, why is the configuration different and which bundle configuration (in this case FrameworkBundle configuration) is dumped on the console?

I am asking because on the book at chapter 4 nothing about this is said.

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: The dumped configuration is after it has all been compiled. You only set a few things in the `app/config/config.yml` but there are many defaults and config settings that may depend on other installed bundles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `app/config/config.yml` is just **overriding** default configuration.

For the framework bundle, the configuration is set up trough Extension (see [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)).

As you can see in this PHP Class `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\FrameworkExtension`, the FrameworkExtension loads some XML files from `Resources/config` directory. That's where are defined all **services** that you can configure in `app/config/config.yml`.

Configuration **structure** and **default values** are set in `FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php`, see [doc about **Defining and Processing Configuration Values**](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/config/definition.html) .

There is a paragraph (**Importing Configuration via Container Extensions**) on the book about this.
It's on page 234 from [symfony 2.5 book](http://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony_book_2.5.pdf).

Comment: Yes it loads a lot of XML files, does all those XML make the default configuration of the framework Bundle dumped by app/console?

Comment: I just checked the DependencyInjection directory and it looks like the Configuration.php file is setting the config structure and defaults values.

Comment: You mean this file: `/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php` ?

Comment: No it's in FrameworkBundle directory, check for this directory in /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/